# regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner 15209 lease expired on region webpage

Tags: java, hbase

I have setup **HBase** in `docker-machine` and boot in standalone mode and everything runs fine after starting HBase. My java program operate the **HBase** smoothly in the beginning, but suddenly exception thrown saying:

```
'regionserver.HRegionServer: Scanner 15026 lease expired on region webpage'
```

**Screenshot Here:**

[image]

and this issue can be reproduced each time.

Below is my startup script:

```
#start HDFS
su -l -c '/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh' hduser

#start YARN
su -l -c '/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh' hduser

#start HBASE
su -l -c '/opt/hbase/bin/start-hbase.sh' hduser

#start HBASE thrift
su -l -c '/opt/hbase/bin/hbase thrift start > 
                  /opt/hbase/logs/thrift.log 2>&1 &' hduser
```

And after the exception, I use jps to checkout, found hregion server and hmaster are all gone:

**Screenshot Here:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have scanned your table to retrieve data, during that time this exception would have been logged in RS log.

This exception arises whenever the scanner timed out to return the requested data to the client. May be you can try increasing the hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period in hbase-site.xml and also make sure that this parameter value is greater than hbase.rpc.timeout

May be you can refer these links

https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/scan_improvements_in_hbase_1

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/admin_hbase_scanner_heartbeat.html